# Force GNU screen to reflow to current terminal width on reattach?

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, putty

I would like to force GNU screen to reflow to the existing terminal width when I reattach a session. It seems to me this worked properly before I upgraded a machine to CentOS 6, but I cannot figure out how to restore it. (`TERM=xterm`)

Whenever I reattach a session, regardless of state when I detached it, it launches at 80 columns, resizing my terminal (PuTTY, in this case) along with it.

I'm launching & reattaching with:

```
screen -aA -R <session>
```

My .screenrc contains only the following, and a few irrelevant key bindings:

```
term xterm

defscrollback 10000

# status line at the bottom
hardstatus on
hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string "${-}%{.0c}%-w%{.y0}%f%n %t%{-}%+w %=%{..G}[%H] %{..Y} %D %M %d, %Y %c | Load: %l"
caption splitonly "%{.yK}%3n t"
caption string "%{.c0}%3n %t"

vbell off

# Fix fullscreen programs
altscreen on
```

Comment: You might have better luck with `tmux`, I can dynamically resize my Terminal window and the tmux inside will follow.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

after you reattach a `ctrl-a F` runs the "fit" command to resize the current window.  if you reattach using the `-A` option it should resize all windows when you reattach.  Are there others still attached to the screen session when you are attaching?  For instance, are you having to use -x to reattach instead of -r?  you can detach others when you reattach with "screen -D -r" instead of "screen -x", and I'd expect this to automatically refit windows.

Comment: I am launching with `-a -A`, and no one else is attached.

Comment: This is still a problem with screen via Ubuntu 14.04.  Fit doesn't work.  Disconnecting and reconnecting does.
Screen 4.2.1 is available from [trusty backports](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-backports/screen). See the [user backports documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports) for information on enabling and using packages from the backports repository.

Comment: Even after doing this, I had to resize my terminal window to send whatever signal `screen` needed to actually do the resize.

Comment: These woraround didn't work for me, perhaps because I am using a different terminal (iTerm2 on Mac). Fit didn't work, so I detached and reattached using `screen -D -r` and even tried resizing the window, but it stayed the same. When in Vim, I can see that `columns` was set to `204`.

Comment: screen -D -r worked for me after trying all the other options, as you said Stew - my screen was still showing up as attached when I ran screen -ls

Comment: probably worth clarifying that this is `ctrl-a shift-f` rather than just `ctrl-a f`.

Answer (score 9):

Note that this answer only applies to PuTTY. I too am forced to use an operating system that I would rather not, and PuTTY is the only real option due to other restrictions on the system. I was having the same issue, my screen would resize upon initiating or connecting to an existing screen session. I tried the answers here to no avail (Windows 10 with PuTTY 0.67 installed via MSI). These answeres might have worked with a standard UN*X terminal, but not with PuTTY, it's a different beastie.

I went digging in the options, and lo and behold under "Terminal -> Features" there is an option labeled "Disable remote-controlled terminal resizing". Check the box, apply the setting, and try screen again. I think you'll find the problem resolved.

Comment: [KiTTY](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/) is a much better drop-in replacement for PuTTY on that OS you're forced to use...

Answer (score 7):

Try adding this (from /etc/screenrc) to your ~/.screenrc:

```
# Change the xterm initialization string from is2=\E[!p\E[?3;4l\E[4l\E>
# (This fixes the "Aborted because of window size change" konsole symptoms found
#  in bug #134198)
termcapinfo xterm* 'is=\E[r\E[m\E[2J\E[H\E[?7h\E[?1;4;6l'
```

https://superuser.com/a/217281/6593

Comment: In [MPutty](http://ttyplus.com/multi-tabbed-putty) this definitively solves putty session not filling the entire page but opening too small